# How to write pipe object to a file in python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pipe, pickle

So I have this requirement where I have to create a pipe for usage in one process say P1, I want P1 to store the pipe information somewhere(probably a file??) so that another process say P2 can read information from this place. I thought of using the pickling concept, but doesn't look like that it will work. I am facing the following issue.

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from multiprocessing import Pipe
>>> p1 = Pipe(False)
>>> fp = open("sample.pkl", 'w')
>>> with fp:
...     pickle.dump(p1, fp)
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1370, in dump
    Pickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 562, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 306, in save
    rv = reduce(self.proto)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py", line 70, in _reduce_ex
    raise TypeError, "can't pickle %s objects" % base.__name__
TypeError: can't pickle Connection objects
>>>
```

I cannot pass information this information at the creation of process P2 because it is completely asynchronous with P1 and ordering should not be ensured between the two(by design). Any suggestions as to how I can overcome this pickling issue or as to what else can I do to make this happen is most welcome!

Comment: Are you trying to store the data FROM the pipe into a file, or the pipe object itself in a file? If it's the latter, that sounds terrifying.

Comment: You say that ordering between P1 and P" has to be completely asyncronous, so it's not clear how/what you are trying to achieve wrt. passing data between the two processes. Could you give some more detail on what problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I was trying to write the pipe object itself, which I realise is a very bad thing to do! To answer the second question, I am trying to create a task manager sort of a thing, which will get tasks through the pipe from another process and handle them! However the task manager might or might not be always active, which is why I want to read the pipe handle for that from a persistent location

Comment: @hemanths It sounds like you need a queuing library like RabbitMQ or ZeroMQ.

Answer (score 0):

I decided that using pipe in this manner was a bad design, I moved over to Named pipe(by mkfifo) for my application